# When do these polynomials majorize the others

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, permutations, permutation-cycles

We say that a $\sigma\in S_n$ is a *cool* permutation if $\sigma(i)\in \{i-1,i,i+1\}$ for each $i$. For example, the following are all the cool permutations for $n=6$. (Here I write the image of $k$ in the $k$-th position)

- **1,2,3,4,5,6**
- **1,2,3,4**,6,5
- 2,1,**3,4,5,6**
- **1**,3,2,**4,5,6**
- **1,2**,4,3,**5,6**
- **1,2,3**,5,4,**6**
- **1,2**,4,3,5,6
- 2,1,**3,4**,6,5
- 2,1,4,3,**5,6**
- **1**,3,2,5,4,**6**
- **1**,3,2,**4**,6,5
- 2,1,**3**,5,4,**6**
- 2,1,4,3,6,5

I colored in the fixed points under the permutations. In this case, there is $1$ permutation that fixes everything, $5$ permutations that fix $4$ elements, $6$ permutations that fix $2$ elements and $1$ permutation that fixes $0$ elements. Now, consider the following function $f_\sigma:\mathbb{N}\to\{0,1\}$ for every $\sigma\in S_n$

$$
f_\sigma(i)=
\begin{cases}
1\;\text{ if }\sigma(i)=i\\
0\;\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
And consider the polynomials

$$p_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{\sigma\text{ is cool}}\prod_{i=1}^nx_i^{f_\sigma(i)}$$
For instance, using the list above, one can compute
$$p_6(x_1,\cdots,x_6)=x_1\cdots x_6+x_1x_2x_3x_4+x_3x_4x_5x_6+\cdots+x_3x_6+1$$
I want to prove that for every $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ integers greater than $1$, one has
$$p_n(x_1,\cdots,x_n)-p_{n-2}(x_2,\cdots,x_{n-1})>\max\left\{p_{n-1}(x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1}),p_{n-1}(x_2,\cdots,x_n)\right\}$$
This is of course true when all $x_i$ are large enough, because the degree of the LHS is greater than the one of the RHS, I want to show that $x_i>1$ for every $i$ is "large enough". I've proved this is the case for $n\in\{1,\cdots,5\}$, but I could go forever and not get anywhere.

Is this hard? This arose while I was trying to prove something about periodic continued fractions; if I'm not lucky with this approach maybe I'll just ask the original question

Comment: What was the original question?  Also, is the original question answered by (for example) chapter 1 of [this pdf](https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-497500429547.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/a06_cont_frac_Khinchin.pdf), or by [this pdf](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/ma330/files/Continued%20Fractions.pdf)?

Comment: @user2661923 No it is not sadly, I've already come across them. The original question (and actually equivalent to this one if I'm not wrong) is about comparing the numbers $p_n-q_{n-1},p_{n-1},q_n$ where $p_n/q_n$ are the convergents for a (irrational) number greater than one. I noticed that if the number had a one in their continued fraction then this behaves weirdly, but if everything is greater than one, the first quantity seemed to always be bigger

Comment: This probably doesn't help, but it looks like the number of cool permutations is the $n$th Fibonacci number, with the convention $F_1=1$, $F_2=2$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It would make a whole lot of sense. The way I came with the definition for cool permutation was via a fibonacci-like recursion